# Camera issues in Samsung j5 (2016) only

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

Currently working on an app in which a functionality of camera interaction is there. I just need to do is to click on a button which opens the camera & the captured picture is shown in an image view after uploading it to the server. The app works totally fine in other Android Devices, but it got stuck in particular Samsung J5 2016. So the question is, it is an issue of ONE UI of samsung or anything else in that particular device. Any help/comment will be appreciable.

Comment: Please paste error stack trace or any other info about issue here. It's not clear what's happening now.

Answer (score 0):

RESET THE CAMERA APP ITSELF...
Apparently, it’s the camera app that has a problem so after the first two steps and the error remains, then you have to go after the app that has an issue. The best thing to do is reset it so it will be brought back to its default settings…

From any Home screen, tap the Apps icon.
Tap Settings.
Tap Applications.
Tap Application manager.
Tap Camera in the default list or tap MORE > Show system apps to display built-in apps.
Tap Storage.
Tap Clear cache.
Tap Clear data and then tap OK.
Restart your.